# SQL: getting sum from one table, one column, different rows

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the last part of a project for my basic SQL course I am currently enrolled in. The professor has not responded to me in days, and it is due tomorrow.

So I have a weird issue I need some explanation on. 
I have a table CUSTOMER with CID, SPONSORID, LAST_NAME, and BALANCE_DUE.
Some customers (cid) sponsor (sponsorID) other customers (cid), and the sponsor is responsible for their balance_due and the balance_due of the customer they sponsor. The friend being sponsored contains the CID of the customer that sponsors them under the SPONSORID column in the friends row on the table. Not all sponsors have a balance_due, but the customer they sponsor may have a balance_due, and vice-versa. I need to create a query that returns the last name of the sponsor, their aggregate friend total, their personal total due, and the TOTAL total due (summing up both what they owe and what their friends owe) using just the last name of the sponsor.

The following code (and result when ran) seemed to work thus far, but for some reason, it is summing up the value for the sponsor Finch (what she owes herself) TWICE (she owes 3.75, but the sum function keeps returning 7.50. The Sum(a.BALANCE_DUE) column is the aggregate correct total for the balance due of the customers she sponsors, but the Sum(b.BALANCE_DUE) column somehow added what she owed twice. The amount shown for Rush is correct, not added twice, like the sum for Finch (rush also has friends, but none owe anything, so only her balance came up) I think somehow because Finch owes some herself, and her friends also owe, the query is summing her personal amount twice because of this, but I just don't understand how.....any pointers?

```
select b.LAST_NAME, Sum(a.BALANCE_DUE), Sum(b.balance_due)
from CUSTOMER a, CUSTOMER b
where a.SPONSORID = b.CID AND b.BALANCE_DUE is not null 
group by b.LAST_NAME;
                    [ Wrote 4 lines ]
SQL> start q11.sql
LAST_NAME  SUM(A.BALANCE_DUE) SUM(B.BALANCE_DUE)
---------- ------------------ ------------------
Rush                                        8.25
Finch                      30                7.5
```

Also, as mentioned, the final output needs to have one last column that totals the overall due for the sponsor based on what they owe AND what the sponsored individual owes (basically adding columns Sum(a.balance_due) and Sum(b.balance_due) putting that output in its own column in the same output table (one query)....still trying to think about how to do this, reviewing my notes......but the aggregate function definitely needs to work correctly first.

NOTE: I know this is an ANSI87 type join, its the professors preference, and its a huge headache.....

Cant add to comments: here's the customer table, no duplicates appear

SQL> select * from customer;

```
   CID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  CATEGORY    SPONSORID BALANCE_DUE
```

---

```
 10001 Rita       Rush       Faculty                      8.25
 10002 Becky      Finch      Faculty                      3.75
 10003 Joyce      Xx_Nestler Friend          10002          20
 10004 Wolf       Xx_Nestler Student                         2
 10005 Vicky      White      Student                       6.3
 10006 John       Kline      Student
 10007 Anya       Rush       Student                       3.5
 10008 Carol      Crane      Friend          10002          10
 10009 Tricia     Tatum      Faculty
 10010 Brian      Price      Student
 10011 Lucy       Nash       Faculty                      1.75
 10012 Larry      Bell       Friend          10001
 10013 Ron        Welsh      Friend          10009
```

13 rows selected.

Comment: Since you're still learning, it's a good habit to follow, use a proper JOIN syntax.

Comment: that's the crux, the professor requires the project report to use HIS FORMATTING PREFERENCE, ANSI87 standard, which has been a huge pain for the whole class, some of us even went to the dean because we want modern, up to date info. This whole semester he required the ANSI87 standard, or we lose 10% of the grade off the top....ridiculous IMHO. he doesnt teach any of the modern methods, his home made textbook for class, while updated, still very dated.

Comment: Could you post the source data for this result?

Comment: You must have duplicated records.  Run the query without the GROUP BY.  Remove the SUM().  See if there's duplicate rows or not.

Comment: LAST_NAME  BALANCE_DUE BALANCE_DUE
---------- ----------- -----------
Rush                          8.25
Finch               20        3.75
Finch               10        3.75

Comment: well format was crap, but see the problem now, it duplicates in the query table because Finch has TWO friends sponsored.........so distinct maybe?.....I have to still total both her friends dues (20+10=30) but only sum hers up once, not twice....

Comment: So ya, still having trouble, but the original query, when removing the sum and group by, returns Rush 8.25 Finch 20(from friend) 3.75 Finch 10(from friend) 3.75(the duplicate value appears here)....so the query table returns, correctly, three rows, one for rush and two for finch (since she has two friends she sponsors) so how can I ignore this duplicate and only total what her friends owe and what she owes one time.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select sp.last_name
     , sum(cu.balance_due) as customer_balance
     , sp.balance_due as sponsor_balance
from   customer sp, customer cu
where  cu.sponsorid = sp.cid
and    sp.balance_due is not null 
group by sp.last_name, sp.balance_due;

LAST_NAME  CUSTOMER_BALANCE SPONSOR_BALANCE
---------- ---------------- ---------------
Rush                                   8.25
Finch                    30            3.75
```

You want the one value that exists per sponsor, so just don't `sum` it.

With ANSI joins it would look like this:

```
select sp.last_name
     , sum(cu.balance_due) as customer_balance
     , sp.balance_due as sponsor_balance
from   customer sp
       join customer cu on cu.sponsorid = sp.cid
where  sp.balance_due is not null 
group by sp.last_name, sp.balance_due;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was working on this problem on my own after reading some tips here......I finally was able to come up with a similar solution, but was still summing and getting a weird result. This though, makes more sense and does indeed work as intended. Now I just need to add a column that totals the total, think I can figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: @DragonWolf the best way to say thank you on SO is to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query to avoid duplicate values

```
Select a.last_name,
       (Select sum(b.balance_due)
             From customer b
             Where b.sponsorid = a.cid
       ),
       a.balance_due
From customer a
Where a.balance is not null
```

Another option is the following (I'm using the old join syntax since you request it)

```
select a.last_name, t.sponsor_sum, a.balance_due
from customer a,
(
   Select sponsorid, sum(balance_due) sponsor_sum
   From customer
   group by sponsorid
) t
where a.cid = t.sponsorid
```

Comment: oracle error @ where b.sponsorid .... ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression...but i think nesting subqueries will be the solution somehow, trying some stuff.

Comment: I believe the group by is not necessary for the outer query, since you want a balance for one person in the last column

Comment: @DragonWolf try it now